# 英語が残っている: 投稿中の draft saved

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 英語

[image: draft saved]

Answer (score 1):

> 下書きを保存しました

Comment: これは適用済みであるはずですが、何か適用していないらしいです。開発者に知らせます。